# Collapsible content using radio button?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to show and hide a text field based on whether or not the user clicks a radio button. Is this possible? According to the docs, collapsible content needs a header.

Here is my code with no collapsible content:

```
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
           <input type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-1" value="choice-1" />
            <label for="radio-mini-1">No</label>

            <input type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-2" value="choice-2"  />
            <label for="radio-mini-2">Yes</label>
    </fieldset>
    <label for="textarea-a">Textarea:</label>
    <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea-a">
    </textarea>
```

I would like the textarea to be shown if the radio button labeled "Yes" is clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to hide/show content based on the state of another element, so you want to bind an event handler to the control element to detect a change in its value and then hide/show the content based on that value. A small bit of research will supply you with more information than you will need.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the `radio` and the `textarea` are siblings (and you're using, and happy to be compatible with up-to-date browsers) you could use CSS:

```
label[for=textarea-a],
#textarea-a {
    display: none;
}

#radio-mini-2:checked ~ label[for=textarea-a],
#radio-mini-2:checked ~ #textarea-a {
    display: block;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ayU4T/1/).

In the above I removed your `radio` elements from the `fieldset` (as the `textarea`, and its `label` *have* to be siblings for this approach to work).